# Stability comparison of europium(II) and ytterbium(II) ions

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stability

“Which one of the lanthanoids given below are most stable in divalent form?” This question was asked in JEE Main 2022 (Indian entrance test for engineering). Now the question had both $\ce{Eu^2+}$ and $\ce{Yb^2+}$ as the options.

My thought was that since $\ce{Yb^2+}$ has $f^{14}$ configuration it should be somewhat more stable than the half filled $\ce{Eu^2+}$. The answer key however says that $\ce{Eu^2+}$ is more stable. It would be helpful if someone could explain why that could be true. Relevant data of Reduction potentials would be helpful as well ( I tried to find it but without much success).

Comment: For Redox potentials, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_%28data_page%29

Comment: Maybe in  $f^{7}$ there is less pairing interactions spin-spin than in $f^{14}$

Comment: Also Yb 2+ is smaller than Eu 2+ so the electrons are on average closer. But you can probably hand wave yourself to whatever conclusion you want.